# google stadia to bluetooth chromium issue

Tags: usb, bluetooth, games, firmware

I'm trying to change the Google Stadia controller to bluetooth mode but i keep getting the issue

> Close other tabs using the controller Couldn’t connect to your
> controller because it’s currently being used by another tab or
> program.
>
> Close any tabs or programs using the controller, then try again.

Is there any fix?

I have used `lsusb` and I can confirm that ubuntu does indeed see the controller/

please help

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ubuntu. Please state your Ubuntu version and provide some logs. Put those infos into your question, not the comments.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. At first I thought it may be that it was connecting to the WiFi; which it was. So I factory reset both controllers. Now they don't connect via WiFi - but I'm still getting this message. I'd be interested to know what you've already tried and/or if you've found a fix for this.

Answer (score 1):

1. On your Linux computer, open the terminal and run the following command from any directory:

```
$ { cat <<EOF
# SDP protocol
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1fc9", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1fc9", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0d28", MODE="0666"
# Flashloader
KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="15a2", MODE="0666"
# Controller
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="9400", MODE="0660", TAG+="uaccess"
EOF
} | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/70-stadiacontroller-flash.rules
```

2. Next, run the following command:

```
$ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```

Source : https://support.google.com/stadia/answer/13067284

Comment: This is one of the first things Linux users are asked to do. I, myself, have already run both of these, yet the message persists - even after a reboot and update/upgrade. I'd be surprised if the OP hasn't also already tried this. The problem seems to be something else. Very strange.

Comment: For me this worked flawlessly, so I don't get the downvote, it is useful advice.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
I had the same issue. This seems to be a very rare problem.

I've found two fixes:

1. There's one "fix" from the [spinics.net](https://www.spinics.net/linux/fedora/fedora-users/msg516714.html) mailing list. It's not a fix to the actual issue, but it is a means to an end. The poster's fix was to simply use a different OS/machine ... Windows in their case.
2. This is the one I used to fix this odd Stadia controller Bluetooth-ing problem. I use Brave, a Chromium-based browser. After downloading the latest release of Chrome itself (as in Google Chrome Chrome ... not Chromium or any other derivative), it finally worked.

I'm not sure what security measure or site setting Brave is doing - or if there's a specific Google-loaded certificate/key that only comes with a Chrome install; but whatever the case, a fresh Google Chrome install did the trick.